# encoding of labels for fit() in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

working on an image classification problem. below is the model I created

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax')) 
 model.compile(loss=loss_function,
                 optimizer='Adam',
                 metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(features[train], labels[train],
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=no_epochs,
              verbose=verbosity,
              validation_split=validation_split,shuffle=False)
```

Dataset size is 8732

Initial shape of `labels` is **(8732 ,)**. It is a list of integers where each integer stands for a class.

The number of classes is 10. `

first I thought about one-hot encoding labels before using them in `fit()` since I have an output layer with 10 nodes so the shape of `labels` changed to **(8732,10)**
but this leads to an error

**Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (20,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (2, 10)).**

So I decided to keep `labels` **integer array** and it worked fine.

Does `fit()` one-hot encode labels?

Does `predict()` will return array of 10 values or only an integer?

Thanks guys,

Comment: what is your loss function? and what's the shape of features[train] and labels[train]?

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma loss function ="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
shape of features[train] = (6985, 2048) 
shape of labels[train] = (6985,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Does `fit()` one-hot encode labels?**

> No, `fit()` does not changes your labels to one-hot encodings. It just
> takes the inputs and outputs you give, as it is.

**2. Does `predict()` will return array of 10 values or only an integer?**

> `predict()` will return the values according to your last layer.
> Since, your last later is `Dense()` with 10 units, `predict()` will
> give you 10 outputs to each input.

**3. (Statement) So I decided to keep labels integer array and it worked fine.**

> This is because you used loss as `sparse_categorical_crossentropy()`
> which will minimize the difference between the value of your input
> label and the index of your maximum output. You could understand this
> better with an [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/sparse_categorical_crossentropy).

Hope this clear you doubts.

Comment: Thanks, so I will keep my loss function and then inverse the predicted output.

Comment: To get prediction as labels, use model.predict_classes(). This will give just one output i.e. the label of maximum of the 10 outputs.

Comment: Thank you a lot!